# Changing the table layout according to the number of characters of a cell

Tags: visualforce, jquery, css

[image]I have formatted the following tables, as it's shown in the figure below. Actually the png describes the usecase when one of the cells, is really long.

I would like to adjust: the layout of the whole 3 tables(aligning them block-wise), the layout of every single table, to fit the new width of the table that has the highest number of carachters in one of its cells.

I am a bit new in manipulating css properties with jQuery or JavaScript, so anyone who could help, is welcomed.

Thanks!
Endrit

Comment: This is a bit more like the css question, so better look for help somewhere else.

Comment: I am totally in the same opinion as you, but I was hoping, that anyone could have encountered the same problem. I opened the same question in stackoverflow too.